# Testing of ARM Templates using ARM TTK Tool in a DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to use ARM TTK and i am selecting my tests.

One of the tests that i want to run is [apiVersions Should Be Recent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-test-cases#use-recent-api-version)
Now in my ARM template i have a resource block of type "**Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules**".
The latest API version for this resource as per the link [API Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules?tabs=bicep) is 2018-09-15.
This is more than 2 years old and my test is failing as it is not fulfilling one of the conditions.
So how to tackle such kind of API versions if there is no current version available which is within 2 years. Any help is appreciated

learn.microsoft.comlearn.microsoft.com
Template test cases for test toolkit - Azure Resource Manager
Describes the template tests that are run by the Azure Resource Manager template test toolkit.

learn.microsoft.comlearn.microsoft.com
Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules - Bicep & ARM template reference
Azure Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules syntax and properties to use in Azure Resource Manager templates for deploying the resource. API version latest

Comment: I would say just ignore ^^

Answer (score 0):

The issue still available in a [arm ttk issue](https://github.com/Azure/arm-ttk/issues/226) & [arm ttk issue2](https://github.com/Azure/arm-ttk/issues/425#issuecomment-866362802)

To get a API Version for the specific Resource type use below `PowerShell` script.

```
((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).ApiVersions
```

Refer for azure ARM schema generation [azure-resource-manager-schemas](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas#azure-resource-manager-schemas)

Refer for additional Steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/45066194/15997690

Solution is available if the latest version of API available check [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/linting-bicep-codes-in-devops-pipeline-arm-ttk/ba-p/1718204) in your case **No** latest version available for `DevTestLab`.

[image]

Please raise a [support ticket](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) and MS Q&A [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html)

Comment: DelliganeshS-MT I don't see any relevant Tag for putting my question in MS Q&A. Can you tell me which tag to use to put my question

Comment: You can use Azure-devtestlab & azure-dev-tool-integration